# MySQL Partitioning on a small table with potential to grow

Tags: mysql

I have few tables on which I have been asked to perform partitioning. The tables contain less than a 100000 records. There is no requirement to partition it based on time. Partitioning needs to be done on active or inactive records.

The intention is to perform analysis on inactive records after a while.  And the active records are used for reporting.

The growth rate of the tables is slow.

So, in this case is partitioning still a solution to fetch active and inactive records efficiently?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you against partitioning in this particular case.

1. 100k tables with slow table growth are not that big that a decently configured mysql could not handle them without partitioning.
2. You do not even have the definition of active - inactive records. You cannot even guarantee that you could do a partitioning by the expression you come up with.
3. Moreover, to me, the active - inactive categorisation indicates that this is not a stable categorisation, inactive records could potentially be active again, or active ones may become inactive.

Personally, the procedure you described to me is a lot more closer to archiving, than partitioning. In archiving you regularly evaluate your existing data and move the unnecessary records out of the primary tables to

- a set of secondary tables (if you still want to mainatin a level of queryability of the archived data)
- a backup